# authentication wsse symfony2 and JavaScript (phonegap)

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, cordova, wsse

in the fact to use authentication wsse with symfony2 via rest, I adopt to develop my client with phonegap, I already develop an algorithm that generates the token in the server part, but every time I have to return the password, which is dangerous, so the best solution is to send only the token generate in the client, and once it is utilise the server it would be destroyed  ,my question is how I can develop a algorithm similar a "encodePassword" of symfony2 in the client side (JavaScript).

**here is the class  that generate the password in symfony2**

```
class MessageDigestPasswordEncoder extends BasePasswordEncoder{


private $algorithm;
private $encodeHashAsBase64;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string  $algorithm          The digest algorithm to use
 * @param Boolean $encodeHashAsBase64 Whether to base64 encode the password hash
 * @param integer $iterations         The number of iterations to use to stretch the password hash
 */
public function __construct($algorithm = 'sha512', $encodeHashAsBase64 = true, $iterations = 5000)
{
    $this->algorithm = $algorithm;
    $this->encodeHashAsBase64 = $encodeHashAsBase64;
    $this->iterations = $iterations;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function encodePassword($raw, $salt)
{
    if (!in_array($this->algorithm, hash_algos(), true)) {
        throw new \LogicException(sprintf('The algorithm "%s" is not supported.', $this->algorithm));
    }

    $salted = $this->mergePasswordAndSalt($raw, $salt);
    $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $salted, true);

    // "stretch" hash
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->iterations; $i++) {
        $digest = hash($this->algorithm, $digest.$salted, true);
    }

    return $this->encodeHashAsBase64 ? base64_encode($digest) : bin2hex($digest);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt)
{
    return $this->comparePasswords($encoded, $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt));
}
```

}
 **here is my method that generate the token in the client side**

```
public function postTokenCreateAction()
{

    $view = FOSView::create();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $username = $request->get('_username');
    $password = $request->get('_password');

    $um = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $um->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $user->getSalt());

    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Wrong user");
    }

    $created = date('c');
    $nonce = substr(md5(uniqid('nonce_', true)), 0, 16);
    $nonceHigh = base64_encode($nonce);
    $passwordDigest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce . $created . $password, true));
    $header = "UsernameToken Username=\"{$username}\", PasswordDigest=\"{$passwordDigest}\", Nonce=\"{$nonceHigh}\", Created=\"{$created}\"";
    $view->setHeader("Authorization", 'WSSE profile="UsernameToken"');
    $view->setHeader("X-WSSE", "UsernameToken Username=\"{$username}\", PasswordDigest=\"{$passwordDigest}\", Nonce=\"{$nonceHigh}\", Created=\"{$created}\"");
    $data = array('WSSE' => $header);
    $view->setStatusCode(200)->setData($data);
    return $view;
}
```